# C++ Why const LPSTR is different than const char *?

Tags: c++

Why does the following code compiles?

```
void foo(const LPSTR str) {
    str[0] = '\0';
}
```

while

```
void foo(LPCSTR str) {
    str[0] = '\0';
}
```

and

```
void foo(const char* str) {
    str[0] = '\0';
}
```

does not.

It's actually `LPTSTR` in my code so `const` version is `LPCTSTR`...
So can I increase code readability by having something like `const LPTSTR`, or it must be either `LPCTSTR` or `const TCHAR*`?

Comment: I strongly suggest that, if this is not some Win32 API specific code, to not use the Microsoft typedefs in your code, instead use the real types (good for this example) or make more sensible typedefs yourself.

Comment: It is win32 specific, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: But is the problem Win32 specific? If not, you should still abstract away these type aliases. In fact, if you'd simply done so in the first place, you'd have immediately seen what the problem is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If by "problem" you mean "question". The typedefs are what the  question is about...

Comment: @rubenvb: No, I mean problem. The question wouldn't need to exist if the OP had done a little more research, narrowing down the issue a little by abstracting away the type aliases. That's kind of the point!

Comment: @rubenvb: Mike Vine made a fairly good point in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220957/c-why-const-lpstr-is-different-than-const-char#comment63867790_38221014). That pretty much invalidates your unfounded recommendation, and provides rationale, too. Why do you feel the urge to comment on Windows specific questions, when you get it so wrong so often?

Comment: A typedef cannot possibly enforce something like null termination, so I really don't see what his comment has to do with my comment. Thanks for the helpful comment plainly stating "I get it wrong so often". From a perspective of "least surprise", a pointer typedef is troublesome,as evidenced by this question all by itself.

Comment: @rubenvb: Those are [SAL Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx), used for static code analysis. Using the typedef's in place of the native C++ types enables you to catch bugs before they happen. You need to [understand SAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx), though (which apparently you don't, hence my comment on getting it wrong so often).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for clearly showing me where I keep getting it wrong. I would try to avoid the patronizing tone, though. Just a thought. Two conflicting points of view do not make one or the other right or wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A typedef "seals" the type from outside modification. `LPSTR` is a `char *`, period. Adding `const` to that (as `const LPSTR`) adds the `const` to the outside: you get a `char * const`.

What you want is to "inject" the `const` (apply it the pointee, not to the pointer), and that is not possible through a simple declaration syntax with a typedef. So it must be `LPCSTR`, the typedef created for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Not quite the whole answer. As the docs and typedef state a LPSTR is a typedef for a  `_Null_terminated_ char*`. This means in use, and in analysis tools especially, it automatically tells the tools not to treat it as an pointer to 1 or more chars, but specifically a null terminated string (which is by far the largest use for char* in c/c++). This means if you forget the null terminate the string the compiler will tell you so which is excellent - without this information the compiler must see you treating the char* as a string before it can complain you've down it wrong. I digress, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll find that `LPSTR` is an alias of `CHAR *`, while `CHAR` is in turn an alias of `char`. Therefore `LPSTR` is an alias of `char*`.

> Why const LPSTR is different than const char *?

`const` in `const char *` applies to the `char`. In other words, it is a non-const pointer to const object.

`const` in `const LPSTR` applies to `LPSTR`, which as we have discovered is `char*`. Because `LPSTR` is a pointer, this makes the pointer const. It does not have an effect on whether the pointer points to a const or non-const object. So, the type is `char * const`.

---

As for why does `str[0] = '\0';` not compile when `str` is `const char*`, the reason is that you may not modify const objects. It compiles with `char * const`, because you may modify non-const objects.

---

PS. The fact that this question exists, demonstrates how hiding the data-pointer types behind aliases is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. `const LPSTR` is resolved as `char* const` : Only the pointer is constant you can modify its content. Look at its definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230350.aspx). So your first example compile
2. `LPCSTR`is resolved as `const char*` so you can't modify its content. You can see its definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230350.aspx). So your second example does not compile
3. Again with `const char*` you can not modify its content, so your last example does not compile

Answer (score -3):

Because a `LPCSTR` is not the same as a (hypothetical) `CLPSTR`.